# Get a page content with Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to make a basic Zend_Http_Client request, to open a webpage, and get its content.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client("http://wikipedia.org");
$response = $client->request();
```

How can I get the content of the page?
Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `getBody` method:

```
echo $response->getBody();
```